# launch file(.exe) is missing after building rcp application on Jenkins

Tags: java, eclipse, jenkins, eclipse-rcp, jenkins-plugins

During migration of Eclipse rcp application created using eclipse 3.x (Indigo) to Eclipse 4.5.2 (Mars), there is no issue found while running the application from Eclipse 4.5.2.

Also while building the application on Jenkins using ant file, the installer is created. But after the installation of installer, the launch file (.exe) for launching an application is missing.

Also, there is a *cli.exe (command line executable) is present.
But after running it via command line, the below error comes:

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main

What could be the problem? I cannot add the console output of Jenkins, since it is very big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally one issue is resolved.. .exe is creating now after installing the installer.
The reason was I was missing some important plugins which should be added by adding delta packs(for multiple platform builds).
for more info about delta packs, refer https://wiki.eclipse.org/A_Brief_Overview_of_Building_at_Eclipse#Cross-platform_build

Comment: But I am still not able to run command line executable(*cli.exe),
for this I am still getting this error:

**Error: Could not find or load main class org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main**

Comment: Can anyone please help me to resolve the above error?

Answer (score 0):

Well first check your generated **`plugins`** directory, is there a **`org.eclipse.equinox.launcher`** bundle? If not do the following:

1. If you are using a **feature** build, check your **`feature.xml`** if **`org.eclipse.equinox.launcher`** is missing or if the wrong version is being used.
2. If you are using a **plug-ins** build, check your **`ApplicationName.product`** file if **`org.eclipse.equinox.launcher`** is missing or if the wrong version is being used.
3. Check your ant file, if there is a link to the following bundle:
   **`plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.x.x.x.jar`** (x should be some version)
   If so, probably the wrong version is used.

Comment: yes, I am using a **feature** build, and "org.eclipse.equinox.launcher" bundle is present in feature.xml.

And in the ant file, the version of "org.eclipse.equinox.launcher" (1.3.100.v20150511-1540.) is also mentioned in the below way: 

equinoxLauncherPluginVersion=1.3.100.v20150511-1540

Comment: I am still looking for the solution. Please reply asap. It's very urgent to fix.

Comment: So in your target definition (if none defined in your Eclipse/plugins directory) is the bundle org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar?

Comment: Maybe also look through your log, search for "error" and "warning".

Comment: yes org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar is available in my eclipse/plugins directory.

Comment: And there is no such error and warning in the console output of Jenkins job.

Comment: Is there any plugins or jar I need to add in eclipse to create a launch file(.exe )? Just fyi after installing the installer there should be a launch file(.exe)  , *cli.exe (command line executable).

Comment: Your target requires also launch fragments e.g. `org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.400.v20160518-1444`. What "installer" are you talking about, normally if a RCP product is build, the result is a zip file (containing exe, plugins, configurations ..).

Comment: yes, the result is a zip file(containing exe, plugins, configrations, *cli.exe).